# Running Eclipse/Netbeans as an applet

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, applet

Would anyone know if it's possible/easy to strip down Eclipse or Netbeans to its bare core (project tree + code window) and run it as an applet in the browser? How-to hints appreciated.

PS: it's for a simple online IDE

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Eclipse, I don't think this has been done.

If it is possible, this would by by using **[Eclipse RAP](http://www.eclipse.org/rap/)** (Rich Ajax Platform), which actually allows existing RCP applications to be run as Web applications with only minor changes.

[alt text http://www.eclipse.org/rap/images/about/Maildemo-Design.png](http://www.eclipse.org/rap/images/about/Maildemo-Design.png)

The actual work would be to integrate **[JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/)** features within custom project viewer and code Editor.